# Create a SQLAlchemy Model Object Without Updating an Auto-Incrementing Column

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a Model with an auto-incrementing primary key. I want to be able to create an object from that model without an id, throw it away, and not have that Column's id auto-increment. Is that possible?

Assigning `MyModel(id=None)` does not do that.

Assigning `MyModel(id=0)` does not work either. It results in a `Key (id)=(0) already exists.` response.

To clarify: I want to keep the Column as auto-incrementing, but disable that behavior in specific circumstances.

The goal is to have a `MyModel` instance not saved in the database which I can pass to the template and can treat just like any other. For example, I want to print `myModel.attribute` in a template, but without saving `myModel` or incrememting the Column's `id` counter.

This is Postgres/Python/Flask/SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you intend to do with that instance of the model class. Autoincrement values are not assigned until you call `.flush()` or `.commit()`

Comment: "The goal is to have a MyModel instance not saved in the database" - Well, if you create an instance of the model, e.g., `foo = MyModel(…)` and do not use `session.add()` to attach it to a Session then it won't be persisted and therefore it won't affect the identity/serial/sequence value on the server. Would that work for you?

Comment: No, not including a `session.add()` doesn't fix it. The problem is the instance gets auto-flushed. I did find (multiple) solutions, though. I will post them in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the instance is being auto-flushed. Not including `session.add(myModel)` does not fix it, but here are three solutions.

1. `session.autoflush=False`

- this isn't great because it applies to everything after that line

2. `session.expunge(myModel)`

- this might throw an exception and needs to be wrapped in a `try/except`

3. `from sqlalchemy.orm import make_transient` and `make_transient(myModel)`

- this is what I went with